# ddslick method onSelected is running right away

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Im using ddSlick plugin for jQuery and the method onSelected should only run when I have chosen an option from the created Dropdown.

Only problem is that the following code I have seems to run the onSelected as soon as the page loads.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$('#flag').ddslick({
    imagePosition:"left",
    background:"none",
    width:"66px",
    onSelected: function(data){
        var chosenCountry = data.selectedData.value;
        chosenCountry = chosenCountry.toLowerCase();
        if(data.selectedIndex > 0) {
            if( new_url[1] in oc(['de', 'es','fr','it']) ) {
                console.log("translated pages");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("English site");
        }
    }   
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/FpRXC/3/)

Thanks

Comment: Is the above code in a `document.ready` handler?

Comment: Yes its inside a document.ready handler and still fires. Check the JsFiddle. It should not be firing the alert unless a select box has been selected

Comment: I've had a play with it and can't get it to do anything other than what you describe.  I'd get in touch with the developer, if possible, and ask them (unless you want to dive into the code yourself).  I would suggest some "first-time" type flag, but that would break it if it doesn't happen in all browsers, or if you (or another developer) ever update it to another version that doesn't do the same.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you guys find any solution for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have invented a solution after hours of figuring out whats the problem.

I directly change something on the code.

**Note:** you need to use the [unminified version](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Scripts/jquery.ddslick.js) to follow this instructions.

---

**on line 220**

find:

```
function selectIndex(obj, index) {
```

change it to:

```
function selectIndex(obj, index, a) {
```

---

**Line 270**

find:

```
if (typeof settings.onSelected == 'function') {
   settings.onSelected.call(this, pluginData);
}
```

change it to:

```
if (typeof settings.onSelected == 'function') {
    if (a !== true) settings.onSelected.call(this, pluginData);
}
```

---

**And finally on line 146**

find

```
selectIndex(obj, index)
```

then change it to

```
selectIndex(obj, index, true)
```

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: selectIndex(obj, index, true) this statement doesn't work, it gives error on "true" argument.

Comment: Did you try to change the line 220? If it still dont work, you can use the new version of ddSlick, all bug is fixed and have some new cool features added. check http://ddslickremablized.remabledesigns.com/

Comment: Also I'm not sure what version you are using. It is best for you to use the latest version.

Comment: ok, thanks, yes i used the lastest js, but its working now, by the comments of 
Robert E. McIntosh.

Comment: Worked a treat, exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 8):

It's dirty and kludgey, but it worked for a quick fix (was using minified version and didn't want to switch for a small piece of my code).  I just defined a global bool and set it to true on the first load.

```
var _ddlLoaded = false;
$(function () {
    $('#ddl').ddslick({
            data: ddlData,
             onSelected: function (data) {
                if(_ddlLoaded  === false) {
                    _ddlLoaded = true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log(data.selectedData.value);
                }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always check out [ddSlick Remablized](http://ddslickremablized.remabledesigns.com/) it fixes this issue and adds a bunch of other cool features like keyboard, class, and disable/enable support!

or you want to do this your self go to the function

> `function selectIndex(obj, index) {`

than at the bottom of the function you'll find

> ```
> //Callback function on selection
> if (typeof settings.onSelected == 'function') {
>         settings.onSelected.call(this, pluginData);
> }
> ```

remove cut and paste that section above the following comment

> `//If set to display to full html, add html`

and than change the if statement to

> `if (typeof settings.onSelected == 'function' &&
>   ddSelected.text().length > 0) {`

ddSlick Remablized has even been tweeted about by Prashant Chaudhary himself! Check it out here https://twitter.com/chaudharyp/status/268045906442584064

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/FpRXC/3/)

```
   function oc(a){
     var o = {};
     for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
       o[a[i]]='';
     }
     return o;
   }
   var temp = 0;
   $('#flag').ddslick({
     imagePosition:"left",
     background:"none",
     width:"66px",
     onSelected: function(data){
       var chosenCountry = data.selectedData.value;
       chosenCountry =    chosenCountry.toLowerCase();
       if(data.selectedIndex >= 0 && temp==1) {
          if( chosenCountry  in oc(['uk','de', 'es','fr','it']) ) {
             alert("translated pages");
          }
       } 
       temp = 1;
     }   
   });
```